# How do I use the COM library in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, com

How do I use the COM library in Laravel?
I've got the following:

```
$connection = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Class 'App\COM' not found
```

Comment: Namespacing: `$connection = new \COM("ADODB.Connection");`

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker! Put it through as an answer will ya and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks for the incredibly quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is using the `App` namespace; and there is no `COM` class defined within the `App` namespace. The standard PHP `COM` class exists within the global namespace, so you need to specify that this is where the class should be found.

Use

```
$connection = new \COM("ADODB.Connection");
```

The leading `\` tells PHP to look for the class in the global namespace

Comment: Thanks for the explanation